# Fetching Quick Start images list from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, command-line-interface, devops, amazon-ami

I am looking for a way to fetch the images list of Quick Start attribute in AWS (when launching new instance).

I tried multiple ways using CLI describe-images (with various filters) but non have managed to succeed.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.